# Сравнение товаров PHP

Tags: ajax, php

Есть страница на которой циклом (while) выводятся все товары из базы данных. Необходимо реализовать следующее:

- пользователь выбирает 2 товара, кликая мышкой по ним.
- затем нажимает
     кнопку сравнить и происходит переход
     на другую станицу, где располагаются
     эти 2 товара с подробным описанием.

Смысл в том, когда пользователь тыкает на товар ajax'ом отсылается первый id, затем также второй. Проблема заключается в том - как передать эти 2 id, не перезаписывая один другим ?
Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А каким образом вы их храните, что они перезаписываются? Мне кажется все должно быть проще:

1) Пользователь кликает на товар: ajax-ом отправляете на сервер id и кладете в сессию, например:

```
$_SESSION['toCompare'][] = $id;
```

2) Пользователь кликает на другой товар - то же самое, что в п.1, просто добавляете этот id в массив для сравнения (предварительно проверив, не существует ли там уже такой id)

3) Когда пользователь перейдет на страницу со сравнением, достанете id нужных товаров из:

```
$_SESSION['toCompare'];
```

**Update 1:**

```
// ограничение на 2 товара и проверка, чтобы $id не повторялись
if (count($_SESSION['toCompare']) < 2 && !in_array($id, $_SESSION['toCompare'])) {
    $_SESSION['toCompare'][] = $id;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за описанный метод. Еще такой вопрос - как ограничить количество сравниваемых товаров до 2 ? Сделать это ограничение ajax'ом ?

Comment: Перед тем как добавить $id в массив, проверьте его размер. Обновил ответ, чтобы код вставился нормально

Comment: Еще возник такой вопрос. Возможно ли конкретно определить переменную $id для каждого товара ? Например - чтобы было $id_1 и $id_2

Comment: @RageXL, не понял вопроса. $id это переменная, которая содержит в себе уникальный идентификатор товара, который вы посылаете ajax запросом. Например, пользователь кликнул на один товар с идентификтаором 12, затем на другой с идентификатором 13, следовательно в массиве `$_SESSION['toCompare']` будет:

    array(0 => 12, 1 => 13)

Когда пользователь запросит страницу со сравнением этих товаров, то запрашиваете данные о товарах из базы данных и выводите ему:

    $ids = array_implode(',', $_SESSION['toCompare']);
    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id IN (".$ids.")");
    // ...

Comment: Верно. Но поскольку я передаю $id двух товаров для сравнения, те имею 2 переменные $id в массиве. Так вот вопрос можно ли записать значения этих 2 значений в разные переменные, например $id1 и $id2 ? Чтобы потом сделать выборку "SELECT FROM products WHERE id='$id1'" и также со вторым.

Comment: @RageXL, обновил свой комментарий чуть выше, перечитайте его

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.